# Timestamp is converted to wrong date inside AngularJS' interpolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interpolation

Having this timestamp: `1519347000`, I want to convert it into date format inside interpolation like this:

```
{{$ctrl.myTimestamp | date:'MMM d y, hh:mm'}}
```

The resulted values is **Jan 18 1970, 04:02** which is obviously wrong, the correct one should be in this case **February 23, 2018 12:50**

[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NdzVbBQMsWq1mXKVNv2a?p=preview).

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: you're passing a millisecond time, not an actual timestamp

Comment: didn't know that... is it possible to get the correct date from this input?

Comment: you could try `new Date(1519347000)` in the code and display a variable equal to that

Comment: @dadsa multiply by a 1000: `$ctrl.myTimestamp *= 1000;`

Comment: it works fine with @AlekseySolovey 's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have the seconds till [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

The date filter from angular requires the milliseconds. If you multiply your timestamp by a thousand  you get the milliseconds till Unix Epoch.

The easiest fix is as follows:

```
{{($ctrl.myTimestamp * 1000) | date:'MMM d y, hh:mm'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to multiply the value you are passing by `1000` and you can get the proper date